# Why is the Flutter TTS library volume lower than other apps on Android even when my volume is at max?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, text-to-speech

I have a problem with flutter. I'm doing some edits on an app, that use flutter_tts library. I noticed that the volume of that is lower than the volume of other apps, also when the volume of my Android smartphone is setted to max.

I tried this only on Android for now, I seen that the library offer some methods for iOS.

There is a way to resolve that you can suggest me?

I don't know what informations give you in particular, if you need something let me know.

I tried to read documentations of the library, and the code of the class, but I found solutions only for iOS, and I tried to find other library to try to increase the volume of the entire app.

Thanks in advance.